# Remove swipeable gesture in NavigationTabBar

Tags: java, android, static-libraries

I have used [this](https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar) library to add Instagram like layout but I would like to remove the swipe able gesture in the tabs and switch tabs only when the tab is clicked. I am unable to find anything in the functions.

```
public class TabsActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);
    initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("LOGOUT", false)) {
        finish();
    }
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    TabsActivityAdapter dashPagerAdapter = new TabsActivityAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
    viewPager.setAdapter(dashPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    final String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabcolors);

    final NavigationTabBar navigationTabBar = (NavigationTabBar) findViewById(R.id.ntb_horizontal);

    final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(
            new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(

                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home),
                    Color.parseColor(colors[0]))
                    .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
                    .title("Home")
                    .badgeTitle("NTB")
                    .build()
    );

    models.add(
            new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group),
                    Color.parseColor(colors[1]))
                    .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group))
                    .title("Groups")
                    .badgeTitle("with")
                    .build()
    );
    models.add(
            new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile),
                    Color.parseColor(colors[3]))
                    .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile))
                    .title("Profile")
                    .badgeTitle("icon")
                    .build()
    );
    navigationTabBar.setBgColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));
    navigationTabBar.setActiveColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    navigationTabBar.setInactiveColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
    navigationTabBar.setModels(models);
    navigationTabBar.setViewPager(viewPager, 0);
    navigationTabBar.setAnimationDuration(0);
    navigationTabBar.setIsSwiped(false);
    navigationTabBar.setBehaviorEnabled(false);

    navigationTabBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            navigationTabBar.getModels().get(position).hideBadge();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

        }
    });

    }
}
```

activity_tabs.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
    android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"

    app:ntb_badge_position="right"
    app:ntb_badged="true"
    app:ntb_scaled="true"
    app:ntb_tinted="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    app:ntb_active_color="#3d3939"
    app:ntb_title_mode="all"
    app:ntb_titled="true"
    app:ntb_swiped="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone could suggest an alternative library if this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `navigationTabBar.setIsSwiped(false);` in code or from xml

```
<devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
android:id="@+id/ntb"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
app:ntb_swiped="false"
...../>
```

Comment: I have checked the code from lbrary https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar/blob/b2a25e5f9fe80c306106bc6592333cee38d91887/navigationtabbar/src/main/java/devlight/io/library/ntb/NavigationTabBar.java and it's look ok. You can check method onTouchEvent().  Have yout set ViewPager via setViewPager()?